# backbone.js - change or click events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, backbone.js

I am getting started with backbone.js but it seems i am not able to get the first hand code correct. I looked up all the resources but cant figure out what is the problem.

I was expecting changed event getting fired every time i change something in the input box and finally when i click the button, it should fire someAction function. There are no JavaScript errors but nothing happens. no change or click event getting fired.

Can someone please tell me what am i missing here?

Aspx Page:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_Default" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
            el: '#form1',

            events : {
                "click #DoSomething": "someAction"
                },

            initialize: function(){
                //This will bind change event of input controls to below function
                _.bindAll(this, "changed");
                },

                //This function will be fired whenever value in the input is changed
                changed: function(evt) {
                    var target = $(evt.currentTarget),
                    data = {};
                    data[target.attr('name')] = target.attr('value');
                    this.model.set(data);
                    alert('Model Updated')
                },

            //take some action on click of a button
            someAction: function(){
                var fName = this.model.get('FirstName');
                var lName = this.model.get('LastName');
                alert("First Name" + fName + " Last Name " + lName);
                return false;
          }
        });
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span>First Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="txtFirstName" value="Mark" />
        <span>Last Name</span><input type="text" name="LastName" id="txtLastName" value="Waugh" />
        <input type="button" id="DoSomething" value="Login Here" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your functionality should be in a view not a model.

Change `Person = Backbone.Model.extend` to `PersonView = Backbone.View.extend`. Now you actually have to create an instance of the view.

```
$(function() {
  PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  });
  window.personview = new PersonView();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`_.bindAll(this, "changed");` won't bind to the changed event. You need to add `'change input': 'changed'` to your events list. The bindAll isn't needed at all.

Also, I believe this.model is undefined. I think you should be using `this.set(data)` instead of `this.model.set(data)`.

Comment: Thanks. I added model with my View initialization and it solved this.model problem

Answer (score 1):

Relevant fiddle (this is not mine but it works)
http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/C9wew/4/

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.